# Displayport monitor no signal when pc is off or sleep or just turns screen off

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, displayport

I recently bought a new pc with msi 1060 gpu and x99 strix asus motherboard.
I have connected my lg monitor to gpu with displayport and a samsung monitor with hdmi which is working fine.
The problem is when windows turns off the screen after being idle or when pc is turned off or sleep , displayport lg monitor shows no signal for 10 seconds and then turns off and I have to turn it on manualy and windows puts all open windows in one monitor which is another problem.
Is there a way to stop monitor from turning off, maybe from bios or some powersaving mode some where hidden in nvidia settings?

**UPDATE**
I ended up using an HDMI to DisplayPort adapter connecting the displayport to VGA, its not exactly a solution but the only work around that worked for me.
I connected the HDMI cable to the monitor and the adapter to graphic card's displayport and now the monitor stays on after windows turns the screen off.
of course your monitor needs a free HDMI port for this to work.

Comment: This is a common problem with display port. See if your monitor has some kind of powersavings mode that you can disable.